# Is backbiting from an anonymous online account still backbiting?

Tags: sin, backbiting

> Backbiting, backstabbing, or tale-bearing is to slander someone in their absence - to bite them behind their back.  ...  In the Baha'i Faith, Christian, Islamic and Jewish doctrine, backbiting is considered a sin.  -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbiting)

In today's world, we can talk negatively about someone anonymously online, where the victim could view said post.  In this sense the "...in their absence" criteria no longer holds (at least partially).

*Question*: Is backbiting from an anonymous online account still backbiting?  Is it classed as something else?

I presume it's just as sinful (if not moreso) than traditional backbiting.

(There appears to be [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UU6sNZMs7Bw) which might answer this, but YouTube is blocked in China so I don't have access.)

Comment: Backbiting is backbiting - simple. doesn't matter where or how - its the same concept. That's like saying masturbating under the duvet is ok and hidden when its not (masturbating is haram/sin!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Backbiting is always backbiting.Here is something to understand that if you are harmed by someone and you are telling someone about what that person did with you. doing this is not a backbiting because you are telling about the Atrocity he did with you.

Answer (score -1):

It can be thought as "mud sticks". Put yourself into that person's shoes, can you feel good at that time? If you don't want a behaviour to be done against you, you sholdn't do it for another person.